# Changing Company field into subdomain URL jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running an app where a rails 3 app where a user creates a subdomain -> xxxxx.myapp.com

Currently, the signup form has a field for this, but ideally I'd like to have the user enter their company name, and have their subdomain automagically created using jQuery or something like that.

**For example,**

**If the company name entered is Rogers Cable, the subdomain would be rogers-cable or rogerscable.** (Ideally this would update on each keystroke, but also when the form field is no longer in focus woudl work)

I am sure there must be a Jquery library or simple technique to do this around, but I am an absolute jQuery noob, so I've been having a hard time finding it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').keypress(function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(code);
    if ( ! /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(char) ) event.preventDefault();
});
```

and [a fiddle to play](http://jsfiddle.net/R74kS/1/)

and an on change version:

```
$('input').change(function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
});
```

**edit** else there is this alternative, with timeout (note this version accepts "-")

```
$('input').keypress(function (event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var str = $('input').val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\-]+/g, '');
        $('#domain').text(str);
    }, 1);    
});
```

Comment: looks nice. if you want a full "by character", you need to handle keydown to get charcodes 8 (backspace) and 46 (delete), but still need keypress for the case. Moreover, you need event.target.selectionStart and event.target.selectionEnd to insert (or delete) the character at the correct position (if user clicked in the middle of the string), (or positionS if it replaces a selection). I have that code somewhere, yes somewhere... but it's 4am, and I need my 4h sleep. maybe "tomorrow" ;)

Comment: well, I will sleep next week... [check this fiddle ;)](http://jsfiddle.net/R74kS/28/)